# Is there any other way to create function in node.js

Tags: node.js

There are different structure of create function in node.js. 
Like :

```
function abc(){
       console.log('stackoverflow');
    }
```

Is there any new format available and is it usefull?

Comment: Your question suggests lack of research. Node.js relies on JavaScript, all syntax was inherited from it.

Answer (score 4):

### Method#1

`function test(){}; // function declaration`

### Method#2

```
var test = function(){};  // function expression
```

### Method#3

```
var abc = function test(){};   // named function expression
```

### Method#4

```
var test = (function(){        // IIFE that returns a function
  return function(){}
})();
```

### Method#5

```
var Test = new Function();     // Function constructor
```

### Method#6

```
var Test = a => a * 2;     // ES6 arrow function
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the format till EcmaScript 6.

Then, to declare a function, you can use:

```
let result = abc => console.log('stackoverflow');
```